# iptables - DMZ to LAN

Tags: iptables, lan, dmz

I want to connect from DMZ to LAN over TCP port 8080 to client 2.

[image]

## in

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0.1 -s DMZ_IP --dport 80 -j DNAT --to LAN_IP:8080
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d LAN_IP --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT

## out

iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -i br-lan -s LAN_IP -o eth0.1 -d DMZ_IP -j ACCEPT

The first two rules say that requests from DMZ-server S1 comes to the LAN-client C2. This seems to work.
Now the C2 must send the answer back to S1. This seems not to work.

How can I realize this with iptables?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that no gateway was entered on C2. ;-)